# Messages lost while using java sockets readUTF

Tags: java, sockets

I have been dealing with one problem all day and I googled it in many different ways but I just can not find a solution, so I guest is time to ask:

I'm trying to code two apps: the client and the server with java using sockets and everything except one thing works fine: the client won't receive all the messages but only pair ones.

What I am doing is looping a 2D array to send every "x" time a message from the server to the client but for example if the loop send 8 messages the client only receive messages 2, 4, 6 and 8.

I printed in my server side console the output just as a verification that the array is property filled and the server display all the messages but not the client.

Im using this:

```
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
        out.writeUTF(getMACAddress());
        InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
        while (true)
        {
            String input = in.readUTF();
            if (input.equals("finish"))
            {
                System.out.println("Server has closed the connection\nGoodBye!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you read `input` for comparison to `"finish"`, and then you read a whole new string that you never compare.

Instead, you should print `input` in the `else` branch of the conditional, i.e.

```
while (true) {
    String input = in.readUTF();
    if (input.equals("finish")) {
        System.out.println("Server has closed the connection\nGoodBye!");
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Server says " + input);
        //                                  ^^^^^
    }
}
```

Comment: woow you are awesome... this "small" mistake stopped me all the afternoon

Comment: @Alecks You are welcome! If this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that you are no longer looking for an improved answer, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.